# Testcontainers cant seem to communicate - connection refused

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

so i have one container set up like

```
genericContainer
                    .withImagePullPolicy(PullPolicy.alwaysPull())
                    .withExposedPorts(SPRING_BOOT_PORT)
                    .withNetwork(NETWORK)
                    .withAccessToHost(true);
```

this starts up fine and i can ping it.

I have another container

```
S3MockContainer(DockerImageName.parse("adobe/s3mock:2.4.13"))
            .withInitialBuckets(S3_BUCKET_NAME)
            .withNetwork(NETWORK);
```

I cant seem to connect or ping the s3Mock container from within my first test container. I have tried passing in the s3MockContainer.gethost() + getFirstMappedPort()

but it just is not able to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both containers are in the same network. So, in that case, you can use the real ports.

First, update S3MockContainer by adding `withNetworkAliases("s3")`, then you can use `s3:9090` in your spring boot app in order to connect to.

Also, I don't think you need `withAccessToHost(true)`.

Comment: So i added the alias, and then tried to set the url to http://s3:9090..... but it failed to start up

Comment: Can you share an example? I think it will hard to make it work without much context.